# Apache Jmeter read SQL variables from csv file

Tags: jmeter

Need to load test a Oracle database the requirement is to fire sql queries concurrently to the database reading the varaibles from a CSV file is this feasible ?

Have a CSV file with values like

```
Name        Email
Justin      justin@beiber.com
George      george@washington.com
...
Micheal     micheal@jackson.com
```

And then have 10,20,30 users fire of queries like

```
select name,phone,city
from address
where name = <<feild1-from-csv>>
and email = <<feild2-from-csv>>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting your test logic into 2 separate pieces:

1. Load information from CSV and store it as JMeter variables
2. Execute SQL code against Oracle using variables from point 1

In regards to implementation I'd suggest to use 2 separate Thread Groups, the first one will be loading stuff from CSV, the second one will be doing actual testing.

**Important:** don't forget to check "Run Thread Groups Consecutively" box at TestPlan level to assure that second thread group runs **after** first one.

Example configuration of 1st thread group:

1. Counter

   - Start - 1
   - Increment - 1
   - Reference name - counter
2. [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)

   - Filename - path to your csv file
   - Variable names - name, email
   - Delimiter - if you're using TAB - "\t", if comma - "," **without quotes**
   - Allow quoted data - False
   - Recycle on EOF - False
   - Stop thread on EOF - True
   - Sharing mode - All Threads
3. Beanshell Sampler (this one is optional, JMeter 2.10 is smart enough to store variables for you but I prefer to control everything myself)

Code for Beanshell sampler shoud look as follows:

```
props.put("name" + vars.get("counter"), vars.get("name"));

props.put("email" + vars.get("counter"), vars.get("email"));
```

It fetches current "name" variable and stores it as name + counter property.

So given 3 lines is CSV file you'll have following properties:

```
name1=Justin
email1=justin@beiber.com
name2=George 
email2=george@washington.com
name3=Micheal
email3=micheal@jackson.com
```

You can use Debug Sampler to see JMeter Variables and Properties values

After that in second thread group you can refer stored properties as:

```
${__P(name1,)}
```

or

```
${__property(name1,,)}
```

in your JDBC Request Sampler.

Both should work.